# Azure VIP Swap downtime

Tags: azure

i've been reading a mix articles on whether the there will be any downtime on Azure VIP SWAP.

Could someone please confirm whether there will be a downtime when we perform a VIP swap for given service? If there is any downtime what's the max down time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theory is that there shall be no downtime. However there are multiple factors that can cause downtime. Some of these factors are:

- DNS Caching at Microsoft DNS Servers (the change of records of `<guid_based_staging_domain>.cloudapp.net` with `[nameit].cloudapp.net`) - even if the change is directly at DNS server, there is TTL associated with these records, and change cannot be immediate;
- Application recompilation needed - your `staging` deployment might need recompilation of the ASP.NET pages, also known as "cold start";
- Probably other factors

For the reason of how VIP Swap is performed check your other question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've added comment on other question.

Comment: This is plain wrong. You don't get a new public IP... as this could cause several hours or even days of downtime depending on you DNS cache settings. The hole point of VIP swap is that the public IP (Virtual IP) stays the same. In stead he Load Balancer is configured to redirect all traffic to the staging deployment - that thus becomes the Production deployment. Also Application does not need recompile, as the IIS on the deployments are not restarted when doing a VIP Swap - it's only a change in the Load Balancer... not on the server.

Comment: Thomas, the only part you are right about is that I'm actually wrong about changing the public IP Address of `[nameit].cloudapp.net`. I admit it! Everything else what I said it absolute true. And, btw, even if the public IP Address of `[nameit].cloudapp.net` changes, it will not cause ages of DNS refresh. Do your homework to check the TTL for any `[cloud_service].cloudapp.net` domain before being corrective! And last but not least, tell me what happens when you (1) deploy to staging without testing any page, (2) Do a VIP Swap, (3) Hit the production? Aren't your pages compiled then?